# Problemas para enviar o certificado.cer na requisição a uma api com RestSharp C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, restsharp

Estou usando o seguinte código para uma autenticação oauth2 passando o certificado.cer:

```
#region config proxy
var certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
X509Certificate2 cert = new(certificado, secretKey);
certificates.Add(cert);
var options = new RestClientOptions(dataAccess["BT:UrlBaseHm"])
{
   MaxTimeout = -1,
   FollowRedirects = false,
   ClientCertificates = certificates
};            
#endregion

RestClient client = new(options);

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;

RestRequest request = new("request/oauth", Method.Post);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   .AddParameter("client_id", dataAccess["BT:ClientId"])
   .AddParameter("client_secret", dataAccess["BT:ClientSecret"])
   .AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
RestResponse<Response> response = await client.ExecuteAsync<Response>(request);
   if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
      return token;
return $"{response.Data!.TokenType} {response.Data!.AccessToken}";
```

Mais ainda não estou tendo sucesso.
A aplicação lê o certificado, eu passo o certificado no RestClient. Mais ainda não consigo status 200 como resposta. Ao invés disso é retornado uma excepiton *"The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."*

Alguém já passou por esse problema q possa me ajudar.
Dê de jhá eu agradeço!!!!

Comment: *"see inner exception."* o que tem no innerexception?

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido!!!!
Após muito tempo quebrando a cabeça, descobri 2 erros e meu código.
1 - O arquivo a ser enviado não era o .cer, e sim o .pfx.
2 - O certificado q eu preciso passar não é .pfx e sim .p12.
Qual a diferença entre .pfx e .p12?
R: .pfx contem apenas um certificado, .p12 contem mais de um.
Se observar o código, nota q no começo eu joguei um varável do tipo X509Certificate2 em uma Collecton X509Certificate2Collection.
Para resolver a questão eu apena passei o caminho do certificado .p12 e o importei para a Collection.
Resultado:

```
#region config proxy
string certificado = "arquivo.p12";
string secretKey = "000000-0";

var certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificates.Import(certificado, secretKey, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

var options = new RestClientOptions(url/api/oauth/token")
{
    MaxTimeout = -1,
    FollowRedirects = false,
    ClientCertificates = certificates
};
#endregion

RestClient client = new(options);
RestRequest request = new($"request/oauth", Method.Post);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={}&client_secret{},RarameterType.RequestBody);
```